# What is happening on the server with a javascript alert box open

Tags: javascript, html, webserver

I recently was notified that a script had been running for 5 days. It was suggested that it might have been one of 3 possible scripts. One had code structured similar to the following:

**Edit** I had modified the alert message (only) a few days prior to the purported beginning.

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Some message');
</script>

<div id="container">
....
```

The intent was to have the alert viewable before the underlying page loaded.

Could this alert waiting for OK to be pressed in someone's browser have caused the program to run for days ??

(I did question script time limits, but that was dismissed.) I'm just trying to learn about the process of serving pages. Thanks for looking and answering.

Comment: Are you talking about a script running for five days on the webserver? The alert would be display before the rest of the page, but I wouldn't think that'd affect the webserver.

Comment: @nnnnnn That's what I was told.

Comment: _"it might have been one of 3 possible scripts"_ - Couldn't whoever told you identify which script it was? How did they determine that there was a problem?

Comment: @nnnnnn They compared the number of seconds of running with the server logs and in that minute were 3. Pretty scientific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, `alert()` is a client side script. The server completes the processing of the page and sends it to the client. And in your case, the client is the one, which is running now and not the server is suspended.

Consider this small PHP Snippet:

```
<?php
    echo "Script Started!<br />\n"
    sleep(10);
    echo "Script Ended!<br />\n";
?>
```

The page will load only after `10 seconds` of processing by the server and it sends out the fully processed code. So, in anyway, javascript `alert` or client side scripting won't stop server execution.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: That makes sense. I AM puzzled by the claim that the hosting company servers detected high CPU 5 days **after** the script started. But just trying to examine my scripts.

Comment: What do you mean in the 2nd line by, '...and not the server is suspended'?

Comment: *The server doesn't stop its execution expecting the user to click on OK button on the alert box!* :P This is what I meant @DavidC